# Balls and Bins when #balls < #bins

Tags: probability, asymptotics, balls-in-bins

I did some search on Balls and Bins problem. But I haven't found out any bounds when the number of balls ($m$) is less than the number of bins($n$).

I am aware of the cases when $m \geq n$ so will welcome any thought on $m<n$. I will update as well if I get something.

Thanks

Comment: The analysis is very similar. What kind of bounds are you looking for?

Comment: @karmanaut I am looking for an upper bound for the maximum load when $m<n$. So I want something like: "with high probability, the maximum load is O(xxxx)". In that sense, I don't want the maximum load to be too high.